# Windows update failing with error 80244007 "could not search for new updates"

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

Windows 8.1 suddenly reported from the notification area that it hasn't been able to run updates for over a while now. The metro-style update app doesn't tell me much about why the updates are failing, but the desktop-app does have a message (some emphasis mine):

> **Windows could not search for new updates**
>
> There was a problem checking for updates.
>
> Error(s) found: **Code 80244007**

It looks like this:

[image: control panel]

The weird thing is, if I check the update history, I do actually see more recent updates:

[image: recent update history]

I've tried a few things to get this resolved.

**First** I've tried various ways of shutting down- and restarting my PC, hoping it would miraculously start finishing the updates. This did not work.

**Second**, I've gone through [MS Knowledgebase 2883975](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883975) that describes my problem...
...which told me to go to [MS Knowledgebase 2883201](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883201)
...which told me to either run Windows udpate :P
...or to go to the [MS Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/default.aspx)
...where I [should search for "KB2883201"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=KB2883201)
...where I chose [the Windows 8 x-64 download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40521)
...which gave me:

> This update is not applicable to this comptuer

I thought that it made some sense, because the filename has "RT" in it. So I also tried the plain [Windows 8 download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40391), but it presents me the same error message.

**Third**, I did some more searching also got me to [a page](http://www.fixwindows.errorhelpforum.com/solved-windows-error-0x80244007/) that promises this error will be solved by running some "Windows Repair Tool" executable, but the page is very vague and generic so I've held back trying it.

**Finally**, a [related post on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-80244007/8794ba3c-6e3a-4559-82a6-480215f2bf27) suggested running `sfc /scannow`, which I tried but came back with no problems after 100% verification.

As a (probably important) footnote, I think I'm probably debet to this problem. When setting up my PC I mistakenly chose "Windows 8 Enterprise" from my MSDN subscription, even though I'm not in an enterprise situation (I should've picked any kind of "Pro" version I guess). We have no server distributing updates for our domain, or anything like that.

I need my Windows 8 installation to get updates on its own. This has worked just fine in the past, only recently has it started getting problems.

**Anyways: what can I do to get Windows to start updating again?**

---

Here's any additional pieces of info that may (or may not) be important:

- My PC is part of a small domain. We have no centralized updates-distributing server (like I mentioned, I installed the *Enterprise* addition by mistake).

Comment: the code means this: WU_E_PT_SOAPCLIENT_SOAPFAULT:  Same as SOAPCLIENT_SOAPFAULT - SOAP client failed because there was a SOAP fault for reasons of WU_E_PT_SOAP_* error codes. But I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @harrymc :-) the bounty was *super effective*: very shortly after posting the bounty someone answered it! Being a good SO citizen I immediately tested the offered solution, and it solved my problem it seems so I accepted the answer. Like I wrote in my comment to the answer, if the solution holds up I'll also award the bounty. I'm just waiting a little bit, since undoing an awarded bounty isn't possible (whereas undoing an "accept" is).

Comment: The case of the too-fast answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're connected to a domain, I assume it's an invalid Target Group name. 
So what you have to do is to open the registry, and then go to : `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`

And then look for `Target Group` key, export it first (just a backup) then delete it.

Now, restart your computer and check Windows Updates.

Comment: Awesome, your answer led to my solution! The `Target Group` key was set to my domain name. Removing it wasn't enough, but after I also removed (in some order, not sure which fixed it) the `TargetGroupEnabled`, `WUServer`, and `WUStatusServer` keys, updates were working again.

Comment: Let me double check that everything's working fine for next two days, if so I'll happily award you the bounty!

Comment: I'm happy that leaded to a solution, your problem isn't just deleting the Target Group, an invalid Target Group means invalid group membership name, which is one of the core requirement to evaluate update approvals from the WSUS server. So, if is it somehow corrupted or invalid, the WSUS will deny the connection.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on a Windows 10 (1511) computer. In my case, deleting `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb` worked:

```
net stop wuauserv
del C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Datastore.edb
net start wuauserv
wuauclt /detectnow
```

This solution was not my idea, but was suggested by Frank Maxwitat [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3753969-7a79-436d-9820-1bb9d4eb398f/windows-update-client-failed-to-detect-with-error-0x8024400d?forum=winserverwsus#7472cf22-f820-430c-b2d3-043eee100673).

The problem appeared after running the Server Cleanup Wizard on the WSUS server used by this computer. However, there was a different problem before running the cleanup, so it might be that this problem simply got hidden by the other problem before the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such errors when trying to install updates on a Windows 8 pc, when the time was not correctly synchronized with the time server.
That would also clarrify why you see more recent updates in the update history.

Can u check your clock to be correctly synchronized?
If you click on the clock in the taskbar, you can chose for 'Change time and date settings...", then go to the 'Internet Time' tab. When did your pc synchronized the time?
Maybe try to click 'Change settings...', make sure the serveradres is 'time.windows.com' and then press 'Update now'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The date and time settings has no "Internet Time" tab though, perhaps because my PC is part of a domain? Either way, checking the registry it does look like time.windows.com is my time provider. In any case, my PC time seems to be correct.

Comment: Then something else will cause the problem, if I know anything I will let u know.

Comment: You tell us if it's part of a domain...

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I've added it as additional details to my question.